# Run background service immediately on registration WindowsPhone 8.1

Tags: c++11, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have implemented a background service that sends some data to server.
But the service is only triggered after the trigger is fired.
I want the service to fire immediately as and when its registered.
I have tried

- DeviceTrigger
- LocationTrigger
- SystemTrigger(Internet available/Timezone-changed)
- MaintenanceTrigger
- TimeTrigger

but they all are fired when their conditions are met as documented. Does any one have any idea how to get this work, btw I'm on windows phone 8.1 and C++.

PS. I just want my service to get triggered as it is registered.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can’t do that directly. Microsoft is very strict about what background tasks can and cannot do because battery life depends on it.

There’s a workaround.

Move your server-sending functionality from your background service into a separate DLL. Call that DLL from both background service process, and the GUI process. If you need to, in that DLL you can guard shared resources with a named mutex or use any other IPC mechanism that works across processes.